# How does Angular render custom html tags in IE9/10 without the browser getting upset about it?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm messing around with web components and using `customElements.define` will make IE9/10 freak out.

I know Angular supports IE9/10 and when reviewing the DOM tree, it looks like Angular does render the custom element tags.

How does it register those custom tags on older IE browsers?

Answer (score 1):

*How does Angular[sic] register those custom tags on older IE browsers?*

Through the use of necessary polyfills:

https://github.com/webcomponents/custom-elements

Angular userland uses:

https://angular.io/guide/browser-support#polyfills

And it is about a lot more than older IE Browsers:

https://caniuse.com/#search=custom%20Elements%20v1